# How to store value in column depending on another column in same table in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

```
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('products_id');
                $table->integer('stack');
                $table->boolean('state')->default(0)->change();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
```

How to make column **state** check **stack**
if **stack** value more than 1 (**> 0**) **stack** get value ( **1** ) else still its value as default ( **0** )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your `product` model, you could listen for creating an event and add this logic into it like this one

```
public class Product extends Model {
  //.....

  protected static function booted()
  {
    parent::booted();

    static::creating(function ($product) {
        if($product->stack > 1){
             $product->state = 1;
        } else {
            $product->state = 0;
        }
    });
  }
 
 // .....
}
```

there are also other events you could listen for

> Eloquent models dispatch several events, allowing you to hook into the following moments in a model's lifecycle: **retrieved**, **creating**, **created**, **updating**, **updated**, **saving**, **saved**, **deleting**, **deleted**, **restoring**, **restored**, and **replicating**

for more info about this check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events-using-closures) here